# Link to another web server on my home network

Tags: networking, webserver

If I have 2 web servers on my home network, one of which can be accessed via the internet, is there a way to access the other from the internet as well through a link in the first website?

Answer (score 0):

Accessibility from the internet is configured in Your router port forwarding. Web servers use 80 port. I assume this port is forwarded to one of Your web servers local IP address. You could set Your other server on different port, configure Your router and  access it, using Your IP adress and the other port.

```
http://yourip:port/some_page.html
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use 2 ways:

1. ports forwarding, like NAT to forward packets from 1st server to 2nd.
2. using http proxing through .htaccess:

   RewriteRule ^access/(.*)$ http://<2ndserver_IP>/$1 [P]

in this example: customer accessing `http://1server/access/<anything>` link will be proxied to `http://2server/<anything>`